# Auto correction in Web form and how to turn it off

Tags: browser, autocorrect

When writing in a Web form, there seems to be an auto correction, that turns initials of words and converts them to capital letters. I am writing in Germany and the systems seems to autoatically apply German rules for my English writing, which is really embarrassing.

On my tablet computer, I can change to an English keyboard and the problem then disappears. Thus it has something to do with what language my browser expects. Is there a way to disable that auto correction in Firefox, Chrome and/or Explorer?

Comment: This sounds like something on your end — I'm not aware of any such feature in our system.

Comment: It is probably the browser. This appears to be a very international forum so I was hoping, that some other user has faced  --and hopefully solved-- the same problem.

Comment: Yes, that sounds most reasonable. Can I do any better than to flag for moderator attention?